# Qt.AlignHCenter not working and labels not displaying text

Tags: python, pyqt5

I have a group box whose layout is vertical. I want to align it to center but code is not working.The other problem is that the labels of the group box are showing text only once(**Note:** group box is in a for loop). I googled but could not found any result.Here is the import code

```
from PyQt5.QtCore import (QRect, QSize,)
from PyQt5.QtGui import (QFont)
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *
from PyQt5.QtCore import Qt
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets
```

As I have imported it right not (import PyQt5.Qt)
I think it is not relevant but the code for scroll area is.

```
        self.subwin = QtWidgets.QScrollArea(self.centralwidget)
        self.subwin.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(70, 70, 531, 251))
        self.subwin.setStyleSheet("background-image:")
        self.subwin.setWidgetResizable(True)
        self.subwin.setObjectName("subwin")
        self.scroll = QScrollArea()
        self.widget = QWidget()
        self.vbox = QVBoxLayout()
        self.subwin.setWidget(self.scroll)
```

Other discription of scroll area are after the for loop.
The **for loop** is as below

```
        for i in dat:
            lsst = i.split("|")
            g_y = 20
            l_y = 15
            l2n3_y = 40
        

            self.groupBox = QtWidgets.QGroupBox(self.scroll)
#            self.groupBox.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(50, g_y + 90 * mul, 431, 85))
            self.groupBox.setTitle("")
            self.groupBox.setObjectName("groupBox")
            self.groupBox.setMinimumSize(QSize(400, 81))
            self.groupBox.setMaximumSize(QSize(431, 85))
            self.label = QLabel(self.groupBox)
            self.label.setObjectName(u"label")
            self.label.setGeometry(QRect(35, l_y + 90 * mul, 371, 21))
            font = QFont()
            font.setBold(True)
            font.setWeight(75)
            self.label.setFont(font)
            self.label.setIndent(-1)
            self.label_2 = QLabel(self.groupBox)
            self.label_2.setObjectName(u"label_2")
            self.label_2.setGeometry(QRect(35, l2n3_y + 90 * mul, 371, 16))
            font1 = QFont()
            font1.setFamily(u"Arial")
            font1.setPointSize(8)
            font1.setBold(False)
            font1.setWeight(50)
            self.label_2.setFont(font1)
            self.label_2.setIndent(-1)
            self.label_3 = QLabel(self.groupBox)
            self.label_3.setObjectName(u"label_3")
            self.label_3.setGeometry(QRect(360, l2n3_y + 90 * mul, 91, 16))
            self.label_3.setFont(font1)
            self.label_3.setIndent(-1)
            mul = mul + 1
            self.label.setText(lsst[0])
            self.label_2.setText(lsst[1])
            self.label_3.setText("res=" + lsst[2])
            self.vbox.addWidget(self.groupBox, Qt.AlignCenter)

        self.widget.setLayout(self.vbox)        
        self.scroll.setVerticalScrollBarPolicy(Qt.ScrollBarAlwaysOn)
        self.scroll.setHorizontalScrollBarPolicy(Qt.ScrollBarAlwaysOff)
        self.scroll.setWidgetResizable(False)
        self.scroll.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 0, 529, 249))

        self.scroll.setWidget(self.widget)
        self.retranslateUi(MainWindow)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(MainWindow)

    def retranslateUi(self, MainWindow):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        MainWindow.setWindowTitle(_translate("MainWindow", "Yotube Video Downloader"))
        self.b1.setStatusTip(_translate("MainWindow", "Click to start the Download"))
        self.b1.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Download"))
        self.input.setStatusTip(_translate("MainWindow", "Enter URL"))
        self.input.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Paste Url Here"))
        self.b2.setStatusTip(_translate("MainWindow", "Select Resolution"))
        self.b2.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Resolution"))
if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    app.setStyle('fusion')
    MainWindow = QtWidgets.QMainWindow()
    ui = Ui_MainWindow()
    ui.setupUi(MainWindow)
    MainWindow.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

The image of the program output is.
[image]
[GitHub link to the file](http://github.com/faniAhmed/test/blob/main/t.py)

Comment: please provide a [mre]

Comment: @eyllanesc here is a GitHub link to the file https://github.com/faniAhmed/test/blob/main/t.py .

Comment: The MRE should not depend on an external resource, it should be in your own post. Please read [ask]

Comment: I gave you because I Dont know what code to show else than this

Comment: @farhanjatt Have you read the MRE link given above? The code must be ***both*** minimal *and* reproducible. We must be able to copy, paste and run it possibly without any substantial change. Which is not your case, as we must *complete* it to make it so. Then, 2 things: 1. There's no point in adding a scrollarea to another one if you're not using it; 2. you should never, ***EVER*** edit files created by pyuic (didn't you notice the warning saying you shouldn't do it "unless you know what you are doing"?). Read [using Designer](//www.riverbankcomputing.com/static/Docs/PyQt5/designer.html).

Comment: I read MRE but I am not good in English so sorry. I realised my mistake but could not edit because I was not online. Thanks for the answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When the widget of the scroll area is not resizable, you must set the [`alignment()`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qscrollarea.html#alignment-prop) property:

> By default, the widget stays rooted to the top-left corner of the scroll area.

So, you must explicitly set the alignment:

```
self.scroll.setAlignment(Qt.AlignHCenter)
```

Note that there are lots of other problems with your code, here are the most important ones:

1. the second argument of [`addWidget()`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qboxlayout.html#addWidget) of a box layout is the *stretch*, if you want to only specify the alignment, you must use its keyword:

   ```
    self.vbox.addWidget(self.groupBox, alignment=Qt.AlignCenter)
   ```

   In this specific case it's not necessary anyway, since the center alignment has to be set on the container;
2. your implementation for the label geometry is wrong, as it's based on the scroll container geometry, but the labels are children of the group box: in fact, you can only see the labels for the first group; label positions should be set using the group box coordinate system (no `mul`);
3. besides what explained above, using fixed geometries is always discouraged, especially when dealing with text elements (you don't know the user font, the font scaling and the DPI), as it often results in partially hidden or overlapping text; you should always prefer [layout managers](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/layout.html), as they will ensure that all widgets always have all the space they require in order to show their contents; note: you should use layouts in *all* the interface, not only in the scrolled widgets; there are only extremely rare cases for which fixed geometries are actually preferable, and it's done with extreme care and *actual* knowledge of how Qt and UIs in general work;
4. setting instance attributes in a loop is pointless, as they will be overwritten in every cycle; just use local variables, as the ownership of the parent widgets will ensure that their referenced objects don't get deleted;
5. since you're always using the same fonts, creating new ones in every cycle is wrong; just create them outside the cycle and set them for the widgets you need;
6. while Qt allows setting non-unique objects names, you should not do that; in fact, Qt object names should only be set if actually required: when it's important to have access to dynamically created objects that cannot be accessed in other ways (like using `findChild` or `findChildren`) or if you need object name selectors in style sheets;